# Создание репозитория Android Studio

Tags: git-commit

здравствуйте, был создан чистый проект, подскажите, какие файлы нужно закоммитить чтобы при дальнейшем импорте проект работал правильно?или если проще, какие файлы трогать не нужно
[image: стандартные файлы нового проекта]

Comment: В `.gitignore`, скорее всего, уже записаны все файлы, которые трогать не нужно. Остальные стоит закоммитить

Comment: закоммитил файлы, пишет android framework is detected при импорте из репозитория
нету файлов graddle, напишите пожалуйста какие файлы нужно коммитить

Comment: извини, я не знаю, если никто не ответит за два дня, напиши, я устрою конкурс

Answer (score 1):

Всё что необходимо для работы проекта:

- app
- - src
- - - ...
- - build.gradle
- build.gradle
- settings.gradle

Остальное необязательно. `app` это папка модуля, соответственно правило для него аналогично для других модулей. Всё что внутри папки `src` по идее нужно потому что там обычно сами исходники.